# Controlling Weights at keras.layer During Training

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Say I have the following model(I removed the parameters for simplicity) :

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(,,))
layer_1 =  layers.Conv2D()(inputs)
layer_2 = layers.AveragePooling2D()(layer_1)
layer_3 = layers.Conv2D()(layer_2)
flatten = layers.Flatten()(layer_3)
outputLayer = layers.Dense()(flatten)
model = keras.Model(inputs= (inputs), outputs=(outputLayer))
model.compile()
hist = model.fit()
```

How can I get control over the weights of a specific layer (say: I want to add noise to the weights during every batch training).

I strongly appreciate any kind of help (explanation, examples, sources)

Comment: You can use `get_weights()`, `set_weights()` methods of of `tf.keras.layers.layer`

Comment: Thank you Andrey, should I use these methods in the layer itself or in model.fit() as callback function

Comment: please see in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `get_weights()`, `set_weights()` methods of `tf.keras.layers.layer` - https://keras.io/api/layers/base_layer/#get_weights-method.

I would either use custom loop (see https://keras.io/guides/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch/) or customize `fit()` with `train_step()` (see https://keras.io/guides/customizing_what_happens_in_fit/)